# My MUI ListItem is blue colored when using next/link. How can I fix this?

Tags: next.js, material-ui

I have a MUI `List` component in my React application that displays a series of links using `ListItemButton` and `Link` components from Next.js. However, the links are displayed with an underline and a blue color by default, and I'd like to change that.

I've tried using the `sx` prop on the `ListItemText` component to set the `color` property to `'inherit'`, but it doesn't seem to have any effect. Here's the relevant code:

```
<ListItem disablePadding>
  <Link href="/some-path" passHref>
    <ListItemButton>
      <ListItemText primary="Some link text" />
    </ListItemButton>
  </Link>
</ListItem>
```

[image]

Is there a way to not have the link style?

Comment: Could you please post the code that shows how you applied the **sx** prop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link#if-the-child-is-a-custom-component-that-wraps-an-a-tag, I needed to add `passHref legacyBehavior`:

```
<ListItem disablePadding key={item.path}>
              <Link href={item.path} passHref legacyBehavior>
                <ListItemButton component="a">
                  <ListItemIcon>{item.icon}</ListItemIcon>
                  <ListItemText primary={item.text} />
                </ListItemButton>
              </Link>
            </ListItem>
```